# How to prove that each edge of tree is a bridge?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> How to prove that each edge of tree is a bridge?

---

My attempt:

Tree is a connected graph which has no cycle, and in a connected graph, bridge is an edge whose removal disconnects the graph.

Let G be a tree, and each edge of G is not a bridge.

I should find a contradiction from my assumption.

But, now I can't go proceed. I think by this way I can prove, and I can't express it.

How can I go further?

Comment: @bof Sorry I will edit it

Comment: @bof I cannot see any ambiguity. A tree is a graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path. A bridge is an edge whose removal increases the number of components. One can express the same ideas is slightly different ways of course, but the concepts are standard and well-established.

Comment: @JAEMTO Your edit has not helped. A tree is *not* simply a graph with no cycle, it is a *connected* graph with no cycle!

Comment: @JAEMTO So suppose you remove the edge between points A and B. Can you find a path between A and B after the removal?

Comment: @bof It turns out that you were right!

Comment: @almagest on my assumption that no bridge is in tree? then it may have another vertex adjacent to x and y

Comment: But on my question, it has no such path

Comment: @JAEMTO Ok. Suppose there is an edge AB which is not a bridge. Then after removing it there is a path from A to B. That path cannot involve the edge AB because you have just removed it. So how does that give you a contradiction?

Comment: Then it contradicts to my assumption that there exist not a bridge??

Comment: @almagest Or connect AB again then it is a cycle.this may contradicts that G is a tree

Comment: @JAEMTO Well done! You have solved it.

Comment: @almagest but I got a question. If edge AB is deleted how can I know that it has a path AB? Because G is a tree?

Comment: @JAEMTO No, because you are assuming that it does not disconnect the graph (because you are assuming the edge AB is not a bridge).

Comment: @almagest now I understand thoroughly thanks

Answer (score 1):

> - An edge is a bridge if and only if it is *not contained in any cycle*.
> - A tree has *no simple cycles* and has $(n − 1)$ edges.

- The graphs with exactly $(n-1)$ bridges are exactly the trees.
- A graph with $n$ nodes can contain at most $(n-1)$ bridges, since
             adding additional edges must create a cycle.

[@Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))

Comment: Restating a lot of well-known results without proof does not help towards a proof of the OP's (extremely) simple result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a tree, and suppose that one of its edges $\{v,w\}$ is not a bridge. This implies that removing this edge does not disconnect $G$, i.e., if $G'$ is the graph $G$ with $\{v,w\}$ removed, $G'$ is connected. Hence, there exists a path connecting vertices $v$ and $w$ in $G'$. This path together with $\{v,w\}$ forms a cycle in $G$, which contradicts the assumption that $G$ is a tree. Therefore, every edge in $G$ must be a bridge.